# What are the terms involving the mode's frequency?

Tags: terminology, mode, finite-population

Suppose I have a finite multiset of $n$ elements (a "population" I guess we can call it). Suppose this set has a proper mode, appearing m out of $n$ times. What term(s) do statisticians use:

1. For  $m$?
2. For the ratio $m/n$?

Comment: 1. Absolute frequency of the modal value (or mode) 2. Relative frequency of the modal value (or mode)

Comment: @Gio: And those are the shortest terms for them? :-(  Also, if I say "frequency of the mode", would this be construed as the absolute or the relative frequency?

Comment: They are the shortest (clear) terms that I know. I am a Statistician, but there can be other terms that I don't know.  I have seen people use the term "frequency" referring to both absolute and relative frequency and the precise meaning was clear from the context.

Comment: @Gio: Ok, so - I guess you could make that an answer which I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Absolute frequency of the modal value (or mode)
2. Relative frequency of the modal value (or mode)

They are the shortest (clear) terms that I know. I am a statistician, but there can be other terms that I don't know. I have seen people use the term "frequency" to refer to both absolute and relative frequency and the precise meaning was clear from the context.